# remove the list of items from a different list

Tags: coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion and i have query regarding removing items from a list and keep only the items which are existing in both the lists.

i checked the [cflib.org](http://www.cflib.org) website to find something relevant but i could find the one which i need

something like this will work

```
<cfset itemsToKeep = ListRemove(ListWhichhasallData,removalItems)>
```

Trying to make it easy so i should not have to make it more complex.

Comment: The examples on cflib, and list functions documentation, should have given you *some* ideas where to start :) What have you tried so far, and what was the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) to keep only the items which exists in both the lists.

```
<cfset list1 = "a,b,c,d,e">
<cfset list2 = "b,d,f">

<!--- Convert list to array --->
<cfset array1 = list1.listToArray(",")>
<cfset array2 = list2.listToArray(",")>

<!--- Retain only the items which are existing in both the lists. --->
<cfset array1.retainAll(array2)>

<!--- Output --->
<cfoutput>#array1.toList(",")#</cfoutput>
```

Here is the [`TryCF`](http://trycf.com/gist/b386bb6d8db1ae7b9feef7ef8c161834/acf2016?theme=monokai).

**Note:-** Java functions are **case & type sensitive** unlike most ColdFusion functions.

Comment: What a time saver! Thanks for sharing, Beginner.

Comment: @Beginner not to hijack this answer, but what if you wanted the items that were NOT retained?

Comment: @HPWD There are multiple ways, one of which is https://trycf.com/gist/c2abbbf4fdd0352681970e7fcb0c1621/acf2016?theme=monokai